# Why is SQL timestamp comparison not working?

Tags: sql, db2-400

In SQL where clause there is a comparison to a timestamp field:

```
timecrtd > '2017-03-01-00.00.00.000000'
```

However, data returned suggests the comparison is not working.

Comment: show us test input & output data?

Comment: Try wrapping the constant in `timestamp()`.

Comment: To have a dash in an identifier, it has to be delimited, as `"processing-date" > '2017-...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of your string can't be implicitly converted to a timestamp.
You may need to explicitly use `CAST()` or `CONVERT()`

`'2017-03-01  00:00:00.00'` should work implicitly, however.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I agree with your point about adding a space and colons, tried it without it making a difference, found this in a query I had used recently which seems to work ok: timecrtd>= '2017-04-09 12:00:00.000000'

Comment: You are right - timecrtd > '2017-03-01 00:00:00.000000' works! Thank you.

Comment: '2017-03-01-00.00.00.000000'  works as well, have just discovered there are other issues with my where clause which made me think it was the timestamp format.